# Cost at all epochs are zero, even before training

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I wrote simple multi-layer perceptron program using TensorFlow.
This program was made to predict following number after 5 sequence. (e.g. 1 4 9 14 19 [24]) Yes, it is very simple.

But I wander to death during at least 4 hours. Because cost at all epochs are zero, even if what I do. Surprisingly, I ensured that weights and biases are initialized to non-zero (using `tf.ones`), it didn't be helped.

How can I not see zero-valued cost, anymore?

**Code**

```
import tensorflow as tf

n_input = 5
n_output = 1
n_hidden1 = 10
n_hidden2 = 10
learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs = 20
batch_size = 100
display_step = 1

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_input], name='X')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_output], name='Y')

with tf.name_scope('H1'):
    w1 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([n_input, n_hidden1]), name='W1')
    b1 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([n_hidden1]), name='b1')
    h1 = (tf.matmul(x, w1) + b1)

with tf.name_scope('H2'):
    w2 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([n_hidden1, n_hidden2]), name='W2')
    b2 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([n_hidden2]), name='b2')
    h2 = (tf.matmul(h1, w2) + b2)

with tf.name_scope('H3'):
    w3 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([n_hidden2, n_output]), name='W3')
    b3 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([n_output]), name='b3')
    pred = tf.matmul(h2, w3) + b3

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()


def generate_sequences(size):
    def generate_sequence():
        from random import uniform
        start = uniform(0, 10000)
        seq = [start + i * (4 + uniform(0, 1)) for i in range(6)]
        return seq[:-1], [seq[-1]]
    seq = list(map(lambda _: generate_sequence(), range(size)))
    return [s[0] for s in seq], [s[1] for s in seq]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    print('Before:', cost.eval(feed_dict={x: [[1, 5, 9, 14, 19]], y: [[24]]}))
    for epoch in range(1, training_epochs + 1):
        batch_x, batch_y = generate_sequences(batch_size)
        _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
        if epoch % display_step == 0:
            print('Epoch:', '%04d' % epoch, 'cost=', '{:.9f}'.format(c))
    print('Optimization Finished!')

    print(pred.eval(feed_dict={x: [[8, 12, 16, 20, 24]]}))
```

**Console output**

```
Before: 0.0
Epoch: 0001 cost= 0.000000000
Epoch: 0002 cost= 0.000000000
Epoch: 0003 cost= 0.000000000
Epoch: 0004 cost= 0.000000000
Epoch: 0005 cost= 0.000000000
Epoch: 0006 cost= 0.000000000
Epoch: 0007 cost= 0.000000000
Epoch: 0008 cost= 0.000000000
Epoch: 0009 cost= 0.000000000
Epoch: 0010 cost= 0.000000000
Epoch: 0011 cost= 0.000000000
Epoch: 0012 cost= 0.000000000
Epoch: 0013 cost= 0.000000000
Epoch: 0014 cost= 0.000000000
Epoch: 0015 cost= 0.000000000
Epoch: 0016 cost= 0.000000000
Epoch: 0017 cost= 0.000000000
Epoch: 0018 cost= 0.000000000
Epoch: 0019 cost= 0.000000000
Epoch: 0020 cost= 0.000000000
Optimization Finished!
[[ 8142.25683594]]
```

Comment: I noticed you're initializing the variables with `tf.ones()`, i.e. an identical value for all weights. This is an extraordinarily bad idea, as it will force all weights to be updated in the same way, since every weight has the same error gradient - excluding the bias, you're effectively learning only one weight per layer. Use `tf.truncated_normal()` or something similar instead for the weights, the biases are then fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you are using loss function for classification (softmax is generally used for classification) while your network could produce an arbitrary single real number, so it's regression, not classification. Use proper cost (say, mean squared error) and your network will start to converge.

In this particular case, just change this line:

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, y))
```

to something like this:

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(y, pred))
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew new truth; subclassification of (un)supervised learning is applied also in deep learning. Right?

Comment: Really don't get what you mean. Deep learning is not something really special, it uses the same principles which are used in classical machine learning, albeit with much bigger networks.